# Asp.net Datasource - view sql data by lookin at datasource object?

Tags: asp.net, datasource, datasourceview

Is there a way to view data that is returned from db by looking at DataSource or DataSourceView object in codebehind? I'm trying to view DataSourceView in debug but I don't see the data returned.

Comment: Might want to put some example code up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataView dv = (DataView) YourDataSourceObject.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
for (int i = 0; i < dv.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string c = dv.Table.Rows[i]["c"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use your datasource to fill a datatable or dataset and you can loop through the records and columns, but if you are looking for something which is going to give you a point-blank representation of the sql results, your best option would be binding it to a datatable.

Comment: so there doesn't seam to be a way to see data by looking just at datasource object?

Comment: I am not certain, but I think in newer versions of visual studio there was a way to see a table-view of data returned when you are debugging and set a breakpoint in the program and you highlight over a datatable/datasource, but this is just from my foggy memory.